# xits-mathbold.otf: Some ugly symbols

Tags: fonts, bold

I do not know how to get equations completely in bold without mistakes with Xits-boldmath. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{xits-bold.otf}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-mathbold.otf}

\begin{document}

Etwas Text:
$\sumint \alpha = c \cdotp \sqrt{a+b} \hbar \BbbQ \, \vec{\jmath} \,
\vec{u} \, \imath$

\begin{equation}
\prod_{j\ge 0}\biggl(\sum_{k\ge0}a_{jk}z^k\biggr) = 
\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n \Biggl(\sum_{k_0,k_1,\ldots\ge 0\atop k_0+k_1+\cdots=n}
a_{0k_0}a_{1k_1}\ldots\,\Biggr) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}}}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

It was compiled by LuaLaTeX. Look at the vector arrows and the square roots. What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there a specific reason for wanting everything boldface? On the other hand, it seems that `xits-mathbold` is buggy.

Comment: Yes, there is. I think that some important equations should be printed in bold. When I use MinionPro and MnSymbol there is no problem.

Comment: So this is not really a **unicode-math** issue as the question says, but specific to a particular font? If that's so, please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: OK, I have corrected this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an specific font `xits-mathbold` which seems to be buggy and we do not from where it comes ...